# Differences Between Dockerfile Instructions in Shell and Exec Form

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What is the difference between *shell* and *exec* form for

`CMD`:

```
CMD python my_script.py arg
```

vs.

```
CMD ["python", "my_script.py", "arg"]
```

`ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ./bin/main
```

vs.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/main"]
```

and `RUN`:

```
RUN npm start
```

vs.

```
RUN ["npm", "start"]
```

`Dockerfile` instructions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are shell form and exec form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904974/what-are-shell-form-and-exec-form)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are two differences between the shell form and the exec form. According to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run), the exec form is the preferred form. These are the two differences:

> The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘).
>
> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

Some additional subtleties here are:

> The exec form makes it possible to avoid shell string munging, and to RUN commands using a base image that does not contain the specified shell executable.
>
> In the shell form you can use a \ (backslash) to continue a single RUN instruction onto the next line.

There is also a third form for [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)

Additionally, the exec form is required for `CMD` if you are using it as parameters/arguments to `ENTRYPOINT` that are intended to be overwritten.

Comment: I'd also note that using the shell form for ENTRYPOINT likely means you're [not propagating signals correctly](https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/) to your app, which can cause problems, in particular in Kubernetes clusters.

Comment: this comment is much more important than the answer, which just repeats the documentation

Comment: It's not useful to just copy and paste the documentation without further explanation!

Comment: What does the documentation mean by "shell string munging"?

Comment: @Rnj I think it means shell expansion. The `variable substitution` part describes it.

Answer (score 4):

In the docker documentation, there is a table that summarizes how `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` interact when they are in the exec form or in the shell form :

[image]

Source : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact