# CMD and ENTRYPOINT bracket vs non bracket version

Tags: docker

I've seen many Dockerfiles with various syntax. Some of them use `CMD` without brackets some of them use brackets. According to my experiments those two are equivalents:

```
CMD ["/bin/ping", "localhost"] 
CMD /bin/ping localhost
```

But this is not true for `ENTRYPOINT` According to my experiments those are not the same and only the version with brackets is working.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

I was experimentig with thosefiles:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:wheezy
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

# WORKS AS EXPECTED - FIRST PASS EXECUTION TO /docker-entrypoint.sh THEN TO CMD
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# PRINTS "PASSED ARGUMENTS" AND EXITS (CMD IS NOT EXECUTED)
# ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh

# WORKS
CMD ["/bin/ping", "localhost"] 

# WORKS
# CMD /bin/ping localhost   

# ERROR
# CMD "/bin/ping localhost"
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "PASSED ARGUMENTS"
echo "$@"
exec "$@"
```

Configuration:

```
wakatana@ubuntu:~/df$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic


wakatana@ubuntu:~/df$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 44
  Running: 8
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 36
 Images: 98
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc version: 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0-99-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 3.83GiB
 Name: ubuntu
 ID: GIQ3:BYEM:O3GZ:OWNP:VROK:V3IV:SVMI:MRZ7:CLHG:GDBR:PG3S:6NQU
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: xclbr
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support


wakatana@ubuntu:~/df$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838
```

I assume that the bracket version is preferred way, but I'm wondering why is non bracket version even allowed to build? Does it have some benefit? Why `CMD` works with both versions when `ENTRYPOINT` works only with bracket version?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940538/596285

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two rules:

1. If you use the JSON-array ("bracket") version, it is an explicit list of "words" that make up the command; if you use a bare string, it is wrapped in `/bin/sh -c '...'`.
2. After applying the first rule, the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are [combined into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).

There is also one detail: if you call [`/bin/sh -c 'command'`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117), any remaining arguments become the positional parameters `$0`, `$1`, *etc.* for expanding the `command` string; they do not get further passed as arguments to the `command`.

So if your Dockerfile says

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/command.sh"]
```

then when Docker launches the container, they will get combined into a single command line

```
/entrypoint.sh /command.sh
```

but if you do it with string form

```
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
CMD /command.sh
```

you will get

```
/bin/sh -c '/entrypoint.sh' /bin/sh -c '/command.sh'
```

which evaluates the string `/entrypoint.sh` and executes it as is, with no arguments; the command gets lost.

Typically you want to allow the command part to be a standard shell command (`docker run --rm -it some-image /bin/sh` is super useful for debugging).  To support this, the `ENTRYPOINT` must be the JSON-array form, and it needs to make sure to run the command passed in its arguments (in a shell script, end with `exec "$@"`).