# Dockerfile CMD does not interpolate ENV

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, dotenv

I have tried every combination I can think of.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  node-server:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - MYVAR=${MYVAR}
    environment:
      - ENV_MYVAR=${MYVAR}
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    # command: ["npm", "run", "_${MYVAR}_"] This works, but for the sake of testing CMD in Dockerfile, I can't get that to work
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14
ARG MYVAR

ENV ENV_MYVAR="${MYVAR}"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE ${port}

RUN echo "1"
RUN echo $MYVAR # Works

CMD [ "npm", "run", "_${ENV_MYVAR}_"] # OUTPUTS as _${ENV_MYVAR}_". Does not interpolate!!
```

**.env**

```
MYVAR=boot
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "node-server-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo 'test'",
    "boot":  "echo 'boot'",
    "_boot_":  "echo '_boot_'"
  }
}
```

**terminal**

```
docker-compose up
```

Expect:

```
npm run _boot_
```

> error - node-server_1  | *${ENV_MYVAR}*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the square brackets.

`CMD npm run "_${ENV_MYVAR}_"`

See this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206384/cmd-and-entrypoint-bracket-vs-non-bracket-version) about the differences