# running uwsgi on docker causing no such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi

I'm trying to run an application using `uwsgi` inside a docker container, but i'm getting

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"uwsgi --http :80 -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock  --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid
>   --wsgi-file /app/api.py -M -p 4 --die-on-term --callable app -d /tmp/uwsgi.log\": stat uwsgi --http :80 -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock  --pidfile
>   /var/run/uwsgi.pid --wsgi-file /app/api.py -M -p 4 --die-on-term
>   --callable app -d /tmp/uwsgi.log: no such file or directory": unknown.

my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential python-dev python-pip

RUN pip install uwsgi

RUN pip install Flask


EXPOSE 9090

COPY ./flask /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["uwsgi --http :80 -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock  --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid --wsgi-file /app/api.py -M -p 4 --die-on-term --callable app -d /tmp/uwsgi.log"]
```

What could i do to run that successfully?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `CMD` exec form

```
CMD ["uwsgi", "--http", ":80", "-s", "/tmp/uwsgi.sock",  "--pidfile", "/var/run/uwsgi.pid", "--wsgi-file", "/app/api.py", "-M", "-p", "4", "--die-on-term", "--callable", "app", "-d", "/tmp/uwsgi.log"]
```

instead of

```
CMD ["uwsgi --http :80 -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock  --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi.pid --wsgi-file /app/api.py -M -p 4 --die-on-term --callable app -d /tmp/uwsgi.log"]
```

Wish this answer is helpful to you and [Dockerfile CMD shell versus exec form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805750/dockerfile-cmd-shell-versus-exec-form) is the reference.