# trouble with multiple parms and RUN

Tags: docker, dockerfile, parceljs

I'm trying to get Parcel Bundler to build assets from within a Dockerfile.  But its failing with:

> No entries found.
>       at Bundler.bundle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:260:17)
>       at  ERROR: Service 'webapp' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c parcel build index.html' returned a non-zero code:
>   1

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8 as base
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

# Development
FROM base as development
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g parcel-bundler
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN parcel build index.html     <----- this is where its failing!
#RUN parcel watch index.html
# Uncomment to use Parcel's dev-server
#CMD [ "npm", "run", "parcel:dev" ]
#CMD ["npm", "start"]

# Production
FROM base as production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY . .
RUN npm install --only=production
RUN npm install -g parcel-bundler
RUN npm run parcel:build
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

NOTE: I'm trying to get this to run in Development mode first.

When I "log into" the container, I found that this command does fail:

```
# /bin/sh -c parcel build index.html
```

But this works:

```
# parcel build index.html
```

And this works:

```
# /bin/sh -c "parcel build index.html"
```

But using these variations in the Dockerfile still do NOT work:

```
RUN /bin/sh -c "parcel build index.html"
```

or

```
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "parcel build index.html"]
```

NOTE: I also tried 'bash' instead of 'sh' and it still didn't work.

Any ideas why its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` and `sh` are indeed different shells, but it shouldn't matter here.  `-c "command argument argument"` passes the entire shell string to `-c`, whereas `-c command argument argument` only passes `command` to `-c` leaving the arguments to be interpreted as additional commands to the shell you're invoking.  So the right invocation is indeed:

```
RUN parcel build index.html
```

or, if you prefer to explicitly do [what Docker will do when it sees RUN followed by a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805750/dockerfile-cmd-shell-versus-exec-form), you can do:

```
RUN [ "bash", "-c", "parcel build index.html" ]
```

But I don't think any of that is your problem.  Looking at your docker file, I think you're probably either:

- missing some files that Bundler needs ( you've only copied in `package*.json` at this point )
- missing some additional config that Bundler needs to function (I don't see you explictly setting 'webapp' but that might be in a `package*.json` file)

I'd put my money on the first one.

Comment: see the difference bwteen shell and exec formats for docker CMD

Comment: ah yes!  I completely missed that.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I didn't copy over the other files because I'm use a bind mount while in development, which is specified when I start up the container (docker run -v...).  Production mode would have transferred the files over.